# DZ.player.prev() not working Deezer API

Tags: deezer

Loading the player with DZ.player.playTracks, the command DZ.player.prev() works fine. But if i use DZ.player.addToQueue to add tracks to the player, the command DZ.player.prev() does not work, it does not return to the previous song.